# requests library for use in AWS Lambda python function

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, python-requests

For my AWS lambda function, I am trying to replace:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
```

with

```
import requests
```

and the AWS documentation suggests to install it like so:

```
pip install requests -t ./
```

But it is not clear to me where I can access the command line to install packages in AWS. Any help is appreciated.

Update, I did search for CLI on the AWS platform, and ran the installation there, but the library is still not available when I run my code.

Update 2: The instructions on the AWS website regarding this (shared in the first comment below, are not detailed enough for me, as I don't quite understand how to implement them.

Update 3: If urllib3 does the trick, I would be happy to use that instead if it saves me the complicated install.

Comment: You appear to be quoting the same information as shown on [Upcoming changes to the Python SDK in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/). That page then mentions: _"For more information on bundling libraries, read [how to build an AWS Lambda deployment package for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/)."_

Comment: I have seen that documentation but it is quite a bit over my head, meaning it gives instructions for folks familiar with a lot of the steps in between. Can anyone provide some guidance what the easiest way might be to resolve this?

Comment: Do you like videos? Here are [some relevant videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=aws+lambda+python+requests).

Comment: thanks everyone for the help. I decided to use urllib3, since it works without the painful installation process.